# Extracting price text Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, extract

I have extracted data regarding houses price from a website, however, the column of prices has text such as "offers over $790,00" I want to be able to extract the price, I have tried

```
 test={'Price':['$593,000','$320,000+ price range','Offers Over $795,000'],'Bedrooms':['3','2','1']}
 Houses=pd.DataFrame(test)
 Houses['Price'].str.extract(pat='([$].)')
```

however, this only extracts the $ and the first digit but it does not extract the entire number.

Comment: "extracts the $ and the first digit" - well, this is exactly what `([$].)` should extract.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A general regex pattern which should work here is:

```regex
\$\d{1,3}(?:\,\d{3})*\b
```

### Demo

Python code:

```
Houses['Amount'] = Houses['Price'].str.extract(pat=r'\$(\d{1,3}(?:\,\d{3})*)\b')
```

If you might have to cater to housing prices which include decimal components, then just use this regex instead:

```regex
\$\d{1,3}(?:\,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?\b
```

Comment: Unfortunately this one just gives me an error "ValueError: pattern contains no capture groups"

Comment: @AusMau Fixed.  Use a raw string for the regex pattern.

Comment: Awesome, this time works, however, now I noticed that there are prices marked with either an m or s at the end for example "Mid to high $700,000s" and this alternative only extracts 700, any way around this? Thanks so much for your help

Comment: Then use: `pat=r'\$(\d{1,3}(?:\,\d{3})*)'` , that is, just remove the word boundary at the end.